# GoogleWebToolkit runtime dynamic layout activities

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I use GWT on client side with activities&places.
I got a layout (LeftSide - CenterSide - RightSide), and each side got it's own ActivityMapper + Activity + View.

I would like to add dynamically Views(With activity) to Sides.
For Example if user's gender is male, then on left side display the AView+APresenter , and BView+BPresenter; but if user's gender is female display only BView+BPresenter.

Can anobody help me about how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: "I gota a layout" - What layout? DockPanel? "How can i do that" - What is the problem, what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a fourth `ActivityMapper` that returns `null` when needed.
Its display region (`AcceptsOneWidget`) can possibly shrink/disappear when passed a `null` widget.

See http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni/ for more context and some sample code.

However, if you're varying depending on the user, and do the authentication outside your app (meaning the app is loaded with a known user and it then never changes, or the app is reloaded with for other user), then you can simply decide at startup (`onModuleLoad`) whether to create that fourth `ActivityMapper` along with its `ActivityManager` and `AcceptsOneWidget`:

```
if (user.getGender() == Gender.MALE) {
  SimplePanel display = new SimplePanel();
  parent.add(display);

  ActivityManager manager = new ActivityManager(new MaleSpecificActivityMapper(), eventBus);
  manager.setDisplay(display);
}
```